# how to merge two or more documents containing arrays of timeseries data using aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to merge two or more documents in such away that the timeseries data in these selected document should be merge into one so that the data of the data should be null if it is not present at that time stamp,for example

Here are the documents(there can be multiple document):-

document 1:-

```
{
  "unit_id":38,
  "mac_id":"abcdefghijkl",
  "data":{
          "ch1":[21,22,31,31,22,11],
          "ch2":[55,55,56,57,88,90]
  },
  "updatetime":["2019-07-15 17:20:16",
"2019-07-15 17:20:23",
"2019-07-15 17:21:23",
"2019-07-15 17:22:23",
"2019-07-15 17:23:25",
"2019-07-15 17:24:25"]
}
```

document 2:-

```
{
  "unit_id":39,
  "mac_id":"abcdefgavdca",
  "data":{
          "ch1":[43.21,55.12,44.21,66.21,11.21,22.10]

  },
  "updatetime":["2019-07-15 17:25:00",
"2019-07-15 17:26:23",
"2019-07-15 17:27:23",
"2019-07-15 17:28:23",
"2019-07-15 17:29:25",
"2019-07-15 17:30:25"]
}
```

Document 3:-

```
{
  "unit_id":40,
  "mac_id":"abcdefgzxcvs",
  "data":{
          "ch1":[21,22,31,31,22,11],

  },
  "updatetime":["2019-07-15 17:35:16",
"2019-07-15 17:36:23",
"2019-07-15 17:37:23",
"2019-07-15 17:38:23",
"2019-07-15 17:39:25",
"2019-07-15 17:40:25"]
}
```

and the result should be like this:-

```
updatetime           ch1[d1]  ch2[d1]  ch1[d2]  ch1[d3]
2019-07-15 17:20:16   21        55       nan        nan
2019-07-15 17:20:23   22        55       nan        nan
2019-07-15 17:21:23   31        56       nan        nan
2019-07-15 17:22:23   31        57       nan        nan
2019-07-15 17:23:25   22        88       nan        nan
2019-07-15 17:24:25   11        90       nan        nan
2019-07-15 17:25:00   nan       nan      43.21      nan
2019-07-15 17:26:23   nan       nan      55.12      nan
2019-07-15 17:27:23   nan       nan      44.21      nan
2019-07-15 17:28:23   nan       nan      66.21      nan
2019-07-15 17:29:25   nan       nan      11.21      nan
2019-07-15 17:30:25   nan       nan      22.1       nan
2019-07-15 17:35:16   nan       nan      nan        21
2019-07-15 17:36:23   nan       nan      nan        22
2019-07-15 17:37:23   nan       nan      nan        31
2019-07-15 17:38:23   nan       nan      nan        31
2019-07-15 17:39:25   nan       nan      nan        22
2019-07-15 17:40:25   nan       nan      nan        11
```

How can i achieve above result,i think i should go with aggregation query,but i don't have any experience with it.

Comment: how many `channels` are possible there like ch1 ,ch2 .... ?

Comment: 1. Take all time stamps from all documents and list them
2. Check every document and fill available time stamps channel for channel

Comment: @ShivamMishra i can't guess it.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly but you can always play around with json.
it will give you all the data required to fulfill what you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            unit_id: true,
            updatetime: true,
            data: { $objectToArray: "$data" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            mydata: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$updatetime",
                    as: "input",
                    in: {
                        unit_id: "$unit_id",
                        date: "$$input",
                        data: {
                            $arrayToObject: {
                                $map: {
                                    input: "$data",
                                    as: "newInput",
                                    in: {
                                        k: "$$newInput.k",
                                        v: { $ifNull: [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$$newInput.v", { $indexOfArray: ["$updatetime", "$$input"] }] }, "nan"] }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$mydata"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "result",
            data: {
                $push: "$mydata"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

#### response

```
{
    "_id" : "result",
    "data" : [
        {
            "unit_id" : 38,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:20:16",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 21,
                "ch2" : 55
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 38,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:20:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 22,
                "ch2" : 55
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 38,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:21:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 31,
                "ch2" : 56
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 38,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:22:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 31,
                "ch2" : 57
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 38,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:23:25",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 22,
                "ch2" : 88
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 38,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:24:25",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 11,
                "ch2" : 90
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 39,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:25:00",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 43.21
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 39,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:26:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 55.12
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 39,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:27:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 44.21
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 39,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:28:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 66.21
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 39,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:29:25",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 11.21
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 39,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:30:25",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 22.1
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 40,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:35:16",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 22
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 40,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:36:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 31
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 40,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:37:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 31
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 40,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:38:23",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 22
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 40,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:39:25",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : 11
            }
        },
        {
            "unit_id" : 40,
            "date" : "2019-07-15 17:40:25",
            "data" : {
                "ch1" : "nan"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: there is list of unique id's,see all three documents "unit_id" is the unique id,

Comment: i have added `unit_id ` and updated the answer.
please check first `project` pipeline, and `map`function in second `project` pipeline.

Comment: this is ok,i got it but Let's say if i want to use $in operator [38,39,40].Such that i got aggregated data of only three unit_id.

Comment: do you need to query or filter the data by `unit_id` is it so ?

Comment: actually both,filter data of only selected douments i.e [38,39,40]

Comment: you can do that using `$match` pipeline.
use match pipeline at the beginning of the query.